# Extract lines having same second column but different third column

Tags: sorting, unix, awk, count

I have a file having strings in 3 columns as below.

```
a b x
a b y
a b z
a c x
a d y
```

I want to extract all the lines having same second column but different third column. The output I am expecting for the above example is

```
a b x
a b y
a b z
```

I tried uniq -f2 and sort -u -k2, But it isn't working as I expect. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
    seen[$2]++ {
        if (!seen[$2,$3]++) {
            printf "%s%s\n", first[$2], $0
        }
        delete first[$2]
        next
    }
    { first[$2] = $0 ORS }
' file
a b x
a b y
a b z
```

Note that the above will work in any awk, for any values in your input file, does not retain the whole of the input file in memory, doesn't rely on any external tools for pre/post processing, and will produce the output lines in exactly the same order they appeared in the input.

Comment: Hi @EdMorton Can you please explain what you did in the script. Its not working for few examples like below `c '74_-_'75 '74–'75
b '74_-_'75 '74–'75
a '74_-_'75 '74–'75` Even @Karakfa's solution was not giving expected results. Can you please suggest where can be the error.

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to show in the comment. If you have sample input that the script doesn't produce the expected output for then edit your question to show it, don't try to include formatted text (code, input, output) in a comment. Make sure you do show the expected output too, though, not just the input.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
Need to make sure all records are unique first

$ sort file | uniq | 
  awk '{c[$2]++; a[$2]=a[$2]?a[$2]RS$0:$0}
    END{for(k in a) if(c[k]>1) print a[k]}'

a b x
a b y
a b z
```

**Explanation:** keep the counter of second field occurrences and aggregate the records.  At the end print the records for which the counter is greater than one.

Comment: That will fail if $2 contains a value that evaluates to zero (or null). You need to test `$2 in a`, not `a[$2]`. You could also get a syntax error in some awks due to the unparenthesized ternary expression. Finally - just use `sort -u` instead of `sort | uniq`.